# Select null or not null depend on parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
    SELECT old.NPP,
       old.NAMA,
       old.JOB,
       pgh.status
    FROM a old
    LEFT JOIN b pgh ON old.person_id = pgh.person_id
                    AND pgh.periode = 2015
                    AND pgh.LAST_STATUS = 1
    WHERE old.UNIT_BESARAN = 'DIVISI TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI'
    AND pgh.status = #status
    ORDER BY pgh.status
```

i want my query can get every value from pgh status, like when i type status 5, the query must to return status is 5, but when i input null, the query will return data from database when the status is null.

how query will be set?

Comment: I don't understand how your query is returning data when the #status is null, as to return nulls in mysql, you have to use `pgh.status IS NULL`. Are you sure the values aren't actually empty strings?

Comment: @Lock the values is empty string, i can get the data null when i use status is null. But status is a parameter, it will be any kinds of value, like 1 or 2 or 3 or null. When i try to use is null, absolutely i can't input 1 or 2 or 3 values. But when i use pgh.status =#status , i can't get null value when i input null, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the condition this way:

```
where old.UNIT_BESARAN = 'DIVISI TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI' and
      (pgh.status = #status or pgh.status is null and #status is null)
```

Comment: when i try to input null in #status, the query is not return any datas

Comment: @user3505775 . . . You have `#status` in your question.  I figured you understand what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your situation correctly, i think there is empty strings, so to make sure the condition is correct. just use `ISNULL`

```
SELECT old.NPP,
       old.NAMA,
       old.JOB,
       pgh.status
FROM a old
     LEFT JOIN b pgh ON old.person_id = pgh.person_id
                    AND pgh.periode = 2015
                    AND pgh.LAST_STATUS = 1
WHERE old.UNIT_BESARAN = 'DIVISI TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI' 
AND pgh.status = ISNULL(#status,'') 
ORDER BY pgh.status
```

Comment: when i try set status parameter value 1, i got the error like "ISNULL": invalid identifier